# Conditional Statements in Excel

Tags: excel

Ok so im trying to create a spreadsheet in excel that automatically tells me who is in what crew for that week. So i have a crew id column and the employees name next to it. I need excel to find all the employees with the number 1 next to it for crew one and put that in a list. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

By the way this is what I have so far. Its only giving me one employee not all of them

```
=LOOKUP(E3,Crew_Code,Employees)

MIKE  1
TIM   2
SAM   1
TY    3
```

I need excel to give me for Group 1

```
MIKE  1
SAM   1
```

Comment: An example picture would be helpful.

Comment: Do you need something automated, or are you okay with using a filter?

Comment: How about a pivot table?

Comment: I need it to be automated, it needs to be as simple as possible for the people who are using it. And let me check on a pivot table i dont know what that is.

Comment: A pivot table will not work. I need to generate multiple lists of employees grouped by a common code say you had the following

MIKE  1
TIM   2
SAM   1
TY    3

I need excel to give me for Group 1

MIKE  1
SAM   1

Comment: You also need to tell us **what should be automated** (i.e. what is the expected output, in which cells...). Note that you can edit your own question with the link `edit` below your question

Comment: @JMax I edited the above question to show what i need.

Comment: I don't need you to write it for me i just need to know which function to use or maybe a better way to do this. The spreadsheet is 6 sheets long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is posible  use SORT VALUE, by team, to sort the data?  it would be easier.

Another, but more complicated solution, is check and seach recursively the data, and require use of two columns, like in the example:
[image: Using recusive search]

in this example I use the following formulaes:

- for G4 or finder column `=MATCH(G$2;OFFSET($C$4:$C$13;SUM($G$3:G3);0);0)`
- for H4 or shower column `=IFERROR(INDEX(OFFSET($B$4:$B$13;SUM($G$3:G3);0);G4);"")`

As you can see the *"finder"* column has the same lenght the data searched, since I don´t have *a priori* the number of members of a team, every search, `MATCH` function, uses the same basic range of search but I displace it, `OFFSET` function, to search *after* the last coincidence found, use of the `SUM` function.

The *Shower* column uses the same principe to look for the values.

**Room for improvement**

- Some $ in the formulae aren´t perfect to "drag ´n copy".
- I need to lear how to upload this excel example file, would help to see more clearly the solution.
- I feel the *Shower* column formulae can be simplificated with a more creative use of `SUM`

I hope this help

Regards Alen